# Custom accordeon menu, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I wrote a menu structure [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VMsh4/). It should be accordion type of menu - when you click an item it opens, when you click another item it opens and the first one is closed.
I tried different things and still can't get it working right. Can someone check the code and tell what has to be added there? Thanks!
The html must stay intact.

```
<ul class="side_menu">
<li><span>Level 1</span>
    <ul>
        <li><span>Level 2</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Level 2</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Level 2</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><span>Level 1</span>
    <ul>
        <li><span>Level 2</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Level 2</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><span>Level 1</span>
    <ul>
        <li><span>Level 2</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
       <li><span>Level 2</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Level 2</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

And here's my js:

```
jQuery(".side_menu li span").click(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).parent("li").hasClass("opened")) 
    {
        jQuery(this).parent("li").removeClass("opened");
        jQuery(this).next("ul").slideUp(200);
    } else {
        jQuery(this).parent("li").addClass("opened");
        jQuery(this).next("ul").slideDown(200);
    };
  });
```

Comment: why you are using `opened` class , are you using it as a flag to check that element is open..    or you have provided some style sheet for `open`

Comment: Arjun, yes there are styles for opened class. See http://jsfiddle.net/VMsh4/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm definitely a fan of less code. Toggling these elements should get you your intended desire. Something like:

```
jQuery(".side_menu li span").click(function(){
    $li = jQuery(this).closest('li');
    $li.toggleClass('open');
    $li.siblings('.open').removeClass('open').find('>ul').slideToggle(200);
    $li.find('>ul').slideToggle(200);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eTVW7/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Chad! I forgot to update my initial fiddle, it should actually look like this - http://jsfiddle.net/VMsh4/2/ (notice level2 styling). Your js works fine, but the Level2 styling is missed - http://jsfiddle.net/VMsh4/4/ Can you check it?

Comment: Just change the class from open to opened.

Comment: Great! One final question - if page loads with "opened" classes already there (some items are open) then it works weirdly. Can you fix it? http://jsfiddle.net/VMsh4/5/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VMsh4/6/ Remove the display CSS for the uls, and do it with JS, because that's how the rest of the show/hide functionality works.